# Python filter and create dict from list of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of dict

```
[{
    'bytesUsed': 79095,
    'servicePlan': '25MB',
    'smsUsed': 0,
    'source': 'Raw Usage',
    'timestamp': '2019-02-28T19:00:00-05:00'
}, {
    'bytesUsed': 310435,
    'servicePlan': '25MB',
    'smsUsed': 0,
    'source': 'Raw Usage',
    'timestamp': '2019-04-01T19:00:00-05:00'
}, {
    'bytesUsed': 286033,
    'servicePlan': '25MB',
    'smsUsed': 0,
    'source': 'Raw Usage',
    'timestamp': '2019-05-06T19:00:00-05:00'
}]
```

Which I want to filter out dict if `timestamp` field is not in the range (2019-02-11T19:00:00-05:00 - 2019-04-10T19:00:00-05:00) and create key:value map like

```
{'2019-02-28T19:00:00-05:00' : 79095, '2019-04-01T19:00:00-05:00' : 310435}
```

Whats is the efficient way to do this ?

at present I am doing it for & if on each dict in list, which it taking time consuming.

Comment: Can you post the code you've already tried?

Comment: Your output is not dictionary. If you call that a key-value map, which of them are key and value?

Comment: I would recommend passing your list of dictionaries to the `pd.DataFrame()` constructor and then filtering from there.

Comment: Your expected output is confusing.  It's not clear what you are seeking.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

start_dt = parse("2019-02-11T19:00:00-05:00")
end_dt = parse("2019-04-10T19:00:00-05:00")

arr = [
    {
        'bytesUsed': 79095,
        'servicePlan': '25MB',
        'smsUsed': 0,
        'source': 'Raw Usage',
        'timestamp': '2019-02-28T19:00:00-05:00'
    },
    {
        'bytesUsed': 310435,
        'servicePlan': '25MB',
        'smsUsed': 0,
        'source': 'Raw Usage',
        'timestamp': '2019-04-01T19:00:00-05:00'
    },
    {
        'bytesUsed': 286033,
        'servicePlan': '25MB',
        'smsUsed': 0,
        'source': 'Raw Usage',
        'timestamp': '2019-05-06T19:00:00-05:00'
    }
]

result = {i['timestamp']: i['bytesUsed'] for i in arr if start_dt <= parse(i['timestamp']) <= end_dt}
print(result)
```

**output:**

```sh
{'2019-02-28T19:00:00-05:00': 79095, '2019-04-01T19:00:00-05:00': 310435}
```

If you don't have [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module, can isntall using `pip install python-dateutil` command. Really didn't get your output, if this is not you expected, please add a comment to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I took at guess at what you're trying get.  Unfortunately your expected output wasn't clear.

I'm always a fan of [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module.

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt1 = parse("2019-02-11T19:00:00-05:00")
dt2 = parse("2019-04-10T19:00:00-05:00")

newdl = []
for dic in dictlist:
    dt = parse(dic['timestamp'])
    if dt1 <= dt <= dt2:
        newdl.append({dic['timestamp'] : dic['bytesUsed']})
print(newdl)
```

output:

```
[{'2019-02-28T19:00:00-05:00': 79095}, {'2019-04-01T19:00:00-05:00': 310435}]
```

If you think you are going to use the datetimes again, I would make `dt` the key instead of the string; it will save you from having to parse the string again later.

Though I would be careful using dates of any kind (string or datetime) as dictionary keys unless you can guarantee they are always unique.